# Ubuntu 16.10 RealTek r8169 capping speeds at 100mb

Tags: networking

I am fairly new to Ubuntu. I have Ubuntu 16.10 and I have noticed my speed is capped at 100mb. I have the RealTek r8169 ethernet card. I know it does up to 1g. Can someone help me please?

I ran ifconfig as requested and this is what it returned. I was told to look for "enp" so I could run a nother command but I do not see it.

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.192  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::6758:6b52:24ca:e40c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 5c:b9:01:04:dd:cb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 152184  bytes 197717227 (197.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 88917  bytes 19919430 (19.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 63880  bytes 3941452 (3.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 63880  bytes 3941452 (3.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.187  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::fccd:fb41:323c:af52  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ac:b5:7d:c0:3d:e2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 43188  bytes 4125698 (4.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3969  bytes 741247 (741.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Does the other side of the connection also supports 1GB?

Comment: Please find out the name of the interface from the terminal: `ifconfig` It will probably be enp-something. Next, run: `sudo ethtool enpxxx` but substitute the interface name you just found. Edit your question to add the result. How do you know that it achieves gigabit speeds? Has it done so with some other operating system? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: To answer the first question, I know my router handles gigabit speeds, as its a gigabit router. AC1900 Linksys. To answer the second question, yes, when I had windows I did receive gigabit speeds. Once I switched over to Ubuntu is when I noticed it was slower. I will do what you said and post in my original question.

Comment: More than likely you're not using a proper cat 5e or cat 6 ethernet cable, or you're running through a switch/hub that doesn't support gigabit speeds (or it's broken). Check your cable. Power cycle your switch/hub.

Answer (score 0):

Basic sanity: do you have your units right? Is it capped at 100 Mega **bit** per second (100Mbps ~ 12MBps) or 100 Mega **Byte** per second? Because the latter is the realistic speed for a 1Gbit link.

Also make sure you're not measuring WiFi speed, as you do have an internal IP address assigned to both interfaces. If wlan (your WiFi) is used as default route, depending on the link quality, you might be experiencing slower that Ethernet speeds. To check the default route, open a Terminal. When terminal is open, type the following command:

```
ip route | grep default
```

Good luck.